# Exit from source command in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have the following shell scripts.

script1

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
echo "foo from Script1"  
}
foo1() {
echo "foo1 from Script1"
}
source script2
foo
fool
```

script2

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
echo "foo from Script2"  
}
foo1() {
echo "foo1 from Script2"
}
```

I am getting the following output:

> foo from Script2
>
> foo1 from Script2

Expected output is

> foo from Script2
>
> foo1 from Script1

I know that source command is playing the spoilsport here. Is there any way to take the control back to Script1 or any other alternative approach to achieve the intention?

Comment: Why would you expect that the `foo` in `script2` should overwrite the `foo` from `script1`, but the `foo1` would not?  Or is that more 'desired output' rather than 'expected output'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sourcing of script2 to affect only the execution of foo, one possibility is to put it in a subshell:

```
( . script2 ; foo ; )
foo1
```

This outputs:

```
foo from Script2
foo1 from Script1
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `readonly` to define `foo1` as read-only before sourcing `script2`.

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
echo "foo from Script1"  
}
foo1() {
echo "foo1 from Script1"
}
readonly -f foo1         # This would define foo1 as readonly
                         # and it wouldn't change upon sourcing script2
source script2
foo
foo1
```

Upon executing `script1` you'd see:

```
script2: line 7: foo1: readonly function
foo from Script2
foo1 from Script1
```

If you want the error (first line in the output not to be printed), redirect the error stream to `/dev/null`, i.e. invoke your script by saying `bash script1 2>/dev/null`.

---

Documentation:

```
$ help readonly
readonly: readonly [-aAf] [name[=value] ...] or readonly -p
    Mark shell variables as unchangeable.

    Mark each NAME as read-only; the values of these NAMEs may not be
    changed by subsequent assignment.  If VALUE is supplied, assign VALUE
    before marking as read-only.

    Options:
      -a    refer to indexed array variables
      -A    refer to associative array variables
      -f    refer to shell functions
      -p    display a list of all readonly variables and functions

    An argument of `--' disables further option processing.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is given or NAME is invalid.
```

Comment: Thanks devnull. Is there any other way to achieve the same without using `source` command?

Comment: @PraveenHassan Achieve what?  Replace `foo` but not `foo1`?

Comment: I may not be able to make the function `foo1` readonly. In that case, are there any other alternative solutions?

Comment: @PraveenHassan Unfortunately, I'm unable to figure what you mean by `I may not be able to make the function foo1`.  Please attempt to be more clear in what you're asking.

Comment: It had to be `I may not be able to make the function foo1 readonly`. Sorry for creating confusion.

Comment: @PraveenHassan In that event, the only suggestion that I can offer is not to `source`.  If it's possible to change `script2`, then there might be other options possible.

Answer (score 0):

Move `source script2` to before declaration of `foo1`

```
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
echo "foo from Script1"  
}
source script2     #Move this line to before declaration of foo1()
foo1() {                                     
echo "foo1 from Script1"
}
foo
foo1
```